# Page created with ReactJs is not indexed by google

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-index, babel-polyfill

I have a news section created with ReactJs, each news post acts as an individual page.
Unfortunately Google is not indexing these pages because of REactJs. I tried to use the babel-polyfill webpack, but it's still not working. Also, I'm making my Ajax call BEFORE rendering the DOM.

Any other ideas for another workaround on this?

Comment: Hi!. It was more of a theoretical question, I have way too many code snippets than just to through them where. Most probably wouldn't make much sense anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

the google crawler won't wait for async requests to resolve, and because your pages are rendered on the users' client, they will appear to be empty pages.

You have two options. Either modify your app to render on the server, this is often called a universal app, or an isomorphic app. There are many tutorials for creating these. The other option is to pre-render static html from your code so that the crawler can see what should be there. There are numerous libraries you can use for this.

The first option is more extensible and probably preferable, but a bit more complex. So make the choice about whats more appropriate for you

Answer (score 1):

It is not indexing them because they are bundled so tat they could be rendered inside your client's browser. What you ought to do is server side rendering.

You can find more about it here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e

Comment: Thank you for you asnwer, I will try with the server side rendering!

Comment: What if I just wanna host my website on Github Pages?